# Get range object as a list of cell objects when passed range is not a string

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been trying to make a function that calculates points in a sheet based on the background color of each cell as long as this cell has a value in it.

this is what I have that is currently working:

```
function calculatePoints(range) {
  var cellArr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range);

  var total = 0;

  for(var i=1;i<=cellArr.getNumRows();i++) {
    for(var j=1;j<=cellArr.getNumColumns();j++) {
      if(  cellArr.getCell(i, j).getValue()!="" ) {
        switch( cellArr.getCell(i, j).getBackground() ) {
          case '#c9daf8':
            total+=1;
            break;
          case '#d9ead3':
            total+=2;
            break;
          case '#fff2cc':
            total+=3;
            break;
          case '#fce5cd':
            total+=4;
            break;
          case '#f4cccc':
            total+=5;
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return total.toFixed(0);
};
```

However, this means that I have to enter the range as a string, meaning that dragging the formaula doesn't update the columns passed in the function, forcing me to manualy write the function.

Is there any way to keep this functionality without passing the range as a string?

Comment: The `getRange()` method has other possible input parameters.  I'm assuming that you are using a1 notation.  [link to documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns)  `getRange(start row, start column, number of Rows to get, number of Columns to get)`

Answer (score 0):

was able to fix it by removing all the parameters needed to be entered when first entering the function and have the function be launched again after every edit

```
function calculatePoints(cell) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var givenCell = cell || sheet.getActiveCell();

  var cellArr = sheet.getRange(givenCell.getRow(), givenCell.getColumn(), sheet.getLastRow(), 1);

  var total = 0;

  for(var i=2;i<=cellArr.getNumRows();i++) {
    for(var j=1;j<=cellArr.getNumColumns();j++) {
      if(  cellArr.getCell(i, j).getValue()!="" ) {
        switch( cellArr.getCell(i, j).getBackground() ) {
          case '#c9daf8':
            total+=1;
            break;
          case '#d9ead3':
            total+=2;
            break;
          case '#fff2cc':
            total+=3;
            break;
          case '#fce5cd':
            total+=4;
            break;
          case '#f4cccc':
            total+=5;
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  givenCell.setValue(total.toFixed(0));
};


function onChange(e) {

  var editRange = {
    top : 3,
    bottom : 9999999999,
    left : 2,
    right : 9999999999
  };
  var thisRow = e.range.getRow();
  var thisCol = e.range.getColumn();

  if (thisRow == 2 && thisCol != 1)
    calculatePoints();
  else if ((thisRow > editRange.top && thisRow < editRange.bottom) && (thisCol > editRange.left && thisCol < editRange.right))
    calculatePoints(e.range.offset((1-SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getRow())+1, 0));

}
```